# Pinescript plot issue

Tags: pine-script

I need to edit my code to plot a buy/sell signal when my position "pos" is =-1 (sell) or the position is = 1 (buy) but the problem is plotting several times I need to plot only every time the position is changed from red to green or vise versa, Note: My Pinescript version is v1,

```
color = pos == -1 ? red: pos == 1 ? green : blue 

plotshape(color , title="Buy", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.normal, text="Buy", transp=0, textcolor = white, color=green, transp=0)
plotshape(color , title="Sell", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.normal, text="Sell", transp=0, textcolor = white, color=red, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find out if the position changed on the current bar.

```
is_new_sell = (pos[1] == 1) and (pos == -1) // pos was buy one bar ago and it is sell now
is_new_buy = (pos[1] == -1) and (pos == 1) // pos was sell one bar ago and it is buy now
```

Then use these variables to plot your shape.

```
plotshape(is_new_buy, title="Buy", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.normal, text="Buy", transp=0, textcolor = white, color=green, transp=0)
plotshape(is_new_sell, title="Sell", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.normal, text="Sell", transp=0, textcolor = white, color=red, transp=0)
```